# each() only working on last object (with foreach loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, each

I'm trying to call a HTML5-Canvas Animation and repeat it in each item with the class `.object`. However javascript only works with last item!

```
<ul>
    <li><canvas class="object"></canvas></li>
    <li><canvas class="object"></canvas></li>
    <li><canvas class="object"></canvas></li>
    <li><canvas class="object"></canvas></li> //this one shows
</ul>
```

```js
$('.object').each(function(){
    var $class = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();    
    var $library = new lib.Animation();
    myAnimation($class, $library);  
});

function myAnimation($class, $library) {
    var $canvas = document.getElementsByClassName($class);
    for (i = 0; i < $canvas.length; i++)  {         
        var $canvas_root = $library;
        var $canvas_stage = new createjs.Stage($canvas[i]);
        $canvas_stage.addChild($canvas_root);
        $canvas_stage.update();
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", $canvas_stage);
    }
}
```

I got it working using ID, however I would prefer to get it working for each item with a class:

```
<ul>
    <li><canvas id="object1" class="object"></canvas></li>
    <li><canvas id="object2" class="object"></canvas></li>
    <li><canvas id="object3" class="object"></canvas></li>
    <li><canvas id="object4" class="object"></canvas></li> //this one shows
</ul>
```

```js
$('.object').each( function() {
    var $id = $(this).attr('id');   
    var $library = new lib.orbeOther();
    myAnimation($id, $library); 
});

function myAnimation($id, $library) {
    var $canvas = document.getElementById($id);     
    var $canvas_stage = new createjs.Stage($canvas);

    $canvas_stage.addChild($library);
    $canvas_stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", $canvas_stage);
}
});
```

Comment: You could change this line `$('.object').each( function() {` to this `$('.object').each( function(idx, obj) {` where the `id` is the looping id (starting from zero) and the `obj` is the actual `canvas` object in the current loop of the array... let me know if that's what you want

Comment: What do I write inside the function?

Comment: @ochi in that example, `idx` is the index of the element within the matched set, nothing to do with the element's `id` attribute

Comment: That is what I meant by the looping id, should had said looping index but it's late here; sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a reference to the element (as in the `each()` code block) then there is little point extracting the class of the element to pass to another function to re-select the element; just pass the element.

Also note that your current logic is flawed as you have a loop within a loop. Try this simplified version:

```
$('.object').each(function() {
    var library = new lib.Animation();
    var $canvas_stage = new createjs.Stage(this);
    $canvas_stage.addChild(library);
    $canvas_stage.update();
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", $canvas_stage);
});
```

Finally you need to fix your HTML as your closing `</canvas` are missing the `>`.

Comment: Yeah, dropped canvas was just a sloppyness when simplyfiying my actual code :). Thx for neat code. This worked swell!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

you should refer to element itself by using $(this).get(0). I haven't try code below yet but it should works.

```
$('.object').each(function(){
    var canvasEle = $(this).get(0);
    var $library = new lib.Animation();

    var $canvas_stage = new createjs.Stage(canvasEle);
    $canvas_stage.addChild($library);
    $canvas_stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", $canvas_stage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd **share this**, since my actual project is using multiple animations, whith different libraries. (That's why I ended up with the double loop that didn't work). So if you have even cleaner ways to do this, please share. Here's the code from my project:

JS:

```
$('.canvas').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $objCol = $this.css('color');
        var $objColBG = $(this).css('background-color');

        //Audio
        if  ( $this.hasClass('orbeAudio')) {
                var $library = new lib.orbeAudio();
        }
        //Photo
        else if ($this.hasClass('orbePhoto')) {
                var $library = new lib.orbeText();
        } 
        //Text
        else if ($this.hasClass('orbePhoto')) {
                var $library = new lib.orbeText();
        }
        //Video 
        else if ($this.hasClass('orbeVideo')) {
                var $library = new lib.orbeVideo();
        }
        //Other 
        else if ($this.hasClass('orbeOther')) {
                var $library = new lib.orbeOther();
        } 

        var $orbeObj_stage = new createjs.Stage(this);

        var $orbeObj_root = $library;
        $orbeObj_stage.addChild($orbeObj_root);
        $orbeObj_stage.update();

        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", $orbeObj_stage);           
});
```